# How to apply middleware to a specific router in express?

Tags: node.js, express

Below code is from http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router. It defines a middleware on express router instance. It works fine but if I define another router and that router will also use the same middleware. Can I define a middleware only for a particular `express.Router()` instance?

```
var app = express()
var router = express.Router()

// predicate the router with a check and bail out when needed
router.use(function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.headers['x-auth']) return next('router')
  next()
})

router.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, user!')
})

// use the router and 401 anything falling through
app.use('/admin', router, function (req, res) {
  res.sendStatus(401)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

To use something specific to a route you can use the .all() function

```
router.route('/')
    .all(function (req, res, next){
        // do middleware stuff here and call next
        next();
    })
    .get(function (req, res) {
    res.send('hello, user!');
});
```